# Non-linear coupled ODE: How to pulse a dynamical system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a set of coupled non-linear differential equations:

$$y'=-a y+i (b+c x+d |y|^2 )\, y+e$$

$$x''+x \omega^2 + \Gamma x'=f  |y|^2$$

where $i=\sqrt{-1}$, 
$y=y(t)$ is a complex number,
$x=x(t)$ is real,
$a,c,e,c, \omega ,\Gamma,f$ are real and positive, $b$ and $d$ can be negative.

I would like to find a set $( a,b,c,d,e,f,\omega ,Γ )$ of parameters so that the time trace of $x(t)$ is a pulsed oscillation.

What do I mean by pulsed oscillation? $x(t)$ should be a sine wave of angular frequency ω with an modulation envelope that looks like pulses with repetition rate $< \omega$ The fft of $x(t)$ should be a comb centered on ω.

In Matlab, I've try to play with the parameters and look at the FFT but it seems like a endless quest... I often find chaos.

I have no idea how to approach this problem and even if it's solvable.

How would you approach it?

PS: I have constraints on my parameters but I think it is irrelevant to speak of it at this stage.

Comment: I'd choose an explicit form for x(t), use it to obtain $|y^2|$ and then study the equation that results from the first one after the substitution of this term.

Comment: ... Anyway, probably you can prove existence or non-existence of solutions, but finding an _explicit_ solution is probably a difficult task.

Comment: I agree with SiD.  Work backwards. Design $x$ that fits your needs then solve the first order equation $y' + (a-ib-icx-id/f(x''+x\omega^2+\Gamma x'))y-e = 0$.

Comment: @SiD
Thanks for the tip.
I'm trying that with mathematica right now. For the envelope I use [this Pulse wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_wave)